# No buttons on blog page on multiligual website

Tags: multilingual, velo

I have created a multilingual website using [this](https://www.wix.com/support/html5/article/tutorial-creating-a-multilingual-site) tutorial but i ran into a problem with my blog(i have one blog for both languages). On the blog page there are buttons but when you open an article there are no buttons. 
Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to access this page is to open a blog in PREVIEW and then click to BACK TO EDITOR. Every time you want to edit something in the blog page you need to do this.